# Follium map : my European locations are plotted in Africa

Tags: geometry, geopandas, folium, shapely, epsg

I would like to use Folium map to plot markers. My locations are in France. I have latitude and longitude information. So I create POINT geometry in order to implement them in Folium map.

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/addresses_geocoded.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'latin-1')
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['latitude'], df['longitude'])] 
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame (df[['type', 'contrat']], geometry = geometry, crs={'init':'epsg:4326'})
```

Then, I create a map and add geodata.

```
map_contrat = folium.Map(location=[45.7174, 4.9036], tiles='openstreetmap', zoom_start=12)
```

As I want to be able to select or hide data from legend, I add geodata using features.

```
folium.features.GeoJson(geo_df[geo_df['contract'] == "A"], name="A").add_to(map_contrat)
folium.features.GeoJson(geo_df[geo_df['contract'] == "B"], name="B").add_to(map_contrat)
```

But, as I understand, due to wrong crs or epsg, my data is not located it the right place.

I am a bit lost with all possibility to chose epsg. It may be a trick to knwow which one to use ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['latitude'], df['longitude'])]` <-- I think these are in the wrong order. x = lon, y = lat.

Answer (score 0):

The most typical CRS is EPSG:4326 which you have used.  Have used a CSV that contains cities in the world and select 100 French cities.  If I use longitude as latitude and latitude as longitude (erroneously transpose them) then the cities appear in Africa!  As demonstrated by red markers in **folium** map.  Correct order (blue) they are in France.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

# 100 cities in france from CSV
df = (
    pd.read_csv(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dr5hn/countries-states-cities-database/master/csv/cities.csv"
    )
    .loc[lambda d: d["country_code"].eq("FR")]
    .sample(100)
)

# incorrect order of lat / lon.  appears in africae
m = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["latitude"], df["longitude"]), crs="epsg:4386"
).explore(color="red", width=300, height=300, name="wrong")

# correct order - all good in France
gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["longitude"], df["latitude"]), crs="epsg:4386"
).explore(m=m, width=300, height=300, name="correct")
```

[image]